# Unable to run Selenium unit test manually in PyCharm

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I have written basic selenium unittest in PyCharm, when I run it, it says

> "C:\Python\Python35\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py" C:\Python\Projects\Questionnaire.py true
>   Testing started at 22:20 ...
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
>   Empty test suite.
>   "

I am new to Selenium. Please guide me how to run from PyCharm

Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest, time
class questionnaire(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("Site i want to access")
        userid = driver.find_element_by_id("userIdInput")
        userid.send_keys("R.vaidya")
        password = driver.find_element_by_id("Password")
        passphrase = "Admin$12345"
        if passphrase == "Admin412345":
            password.send_keys(passphrase)
            submit = driver.find_element_by_id("login")
            submit.click()
            webelement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/div/div/div/span')
            text = webelement.text
            Actaul = "Access Denied! The User Name or Password provided is incorrect or the user has not been set up. Please click on forgot password to reset your password."
            self.assertCountEqual(Actaul,text,"Pass")
        else:
            password.send_keys(passphrase)
            submit = driver.find_element_by_id("login")
            submit.click()
            time.sleep(3)

    def tearDown(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   unittest.main()
```

Comment: tests need to be named like `test_login` in your case.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot.